# ¿ Cómo puedo eliminar el head, los meta y css de un objeto beautiful soup?

Tags: python, scraping, beautifulsoup

estoy haciendo web scraping a una página que tiene una tabla y quiero obtener la información de esa tabla pero siempre que busco la tabla , me trae la información de los meta y los estilos y eso es mucha información que me es inútil.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

secciones=soup.find(id="TableWithRules").find_all("td") #Aca solo quiero que me muestre cada fila y ya.

print(secciones)   #Me muestra las filas pero con el head , css , meta y otras cosas. 
print(type(secciones))  #<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>
```

Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Comment: ¿ Podrías agregar un ejemplo del string que buscas limpiar ?

Comment: Cuando haces `print(secciones)`  beautifulsoup te muestra el HTML completo del cual fue extraido el ResultSet `secciones`. Por eso ves head, meta, y todo lo demás, porque estás viendo el HTML completo y no la parte extraída. Tienes que iterar por `secciones` (es un iterable) e imprimir cada elemento.

Comment: @abulafia, podrías por favor mostrarme cómo hacer eso o algún recurso donde encuentre esa información ?